# Probabilistic convergence for average outcome in coin tossing problem?

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, convergence-divergence

How can I derive a formula that expresses a guarantee of convergence of mean outcome in coin tossing problem as number of trials approaches infinity? I saw a lot of formulae about "convergence in probability", so I wondered how can I do derive such a thing for a simple experiment.

Links, key words for search, references are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use Markov inequality, i.e.
$$\Bbb{P}(|S_n/n - p| > \epsilon) \leq Var(S_n/n)/\epsilon^2 = Var(X_1)/n\epsilon^2 \rightarrow 0.$$